# showing image in a box that has a different image ratio nicely

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an original size of 900x300. I have an image container that has a size of  320x180. When I show this, the image looks squezeed. I understand it's because the ratio is not the same. So I am planning to show a zoomed version of it, but with just manipulating it's CSS. Is it possible? Also open to any other ideas that can show this image nicely using CSS tricks without having it looked squished in this box.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m9aK/) to play with. I am currently setting the `width` and `height` to `100%` and hide overflow's.

Comment: Change `width` and `height` to `max-width` and `max-height` in .boutique-grid .box-container img.
Is that how you want it?
You can then play around with overflows to display that 9 items thing wherever you want.

Comment: I actually want to crop the center of this image such that it sizes to 320x180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the ratio of your image is 3:1. You need to make your container size 3:1 as well... if you want your width to be 320px, then you have to set your height to 106px (106.6px to be exact), or something else proportionate to your original image. Here's an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m9aK/1/)**.

```
.boutique-grid .box-container {
position: relative;
height: 106px;
width: 320px;
}
```

You'll notice it's now proportionate.

Comment: I don't want to set the container size as the same ratio as well... that is why

Comment: I agree with webfrogs. the only way you can keep the image proportions is by mataining the aspect ratio which in your case is 3:1.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question don't supply that what type of zoom you wants, But I can give you an idea, If you want that the image should be zoom at their place, with the full size then use follwoing CSS with the hover property:-

```
.boutique-grid .box-container:hover {
 position: absolute;
 width:900px;
 height:300px;
 }
```

See the fiddle here:-http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/3m9aK/6/show/

Also If you like to provide a zoom with the popup then you can achieve this by following link:-
http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm

If you want to crop the image with the center property and then use in that continer then you should be crop the image with the margin property, by that way you can crop your image with the same aspect ratio. See the post below:-

http://www.squareonemd.co.uk/how-to-crop-an-image-with-a-css-class/

Let me know if it will works...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a zoomed version then you can use css background property in css. Here is the code if this is what you wanted:

```
.box-container {
position: relative;
height: 180px;
width: 320px;
    background:url("http://cf.shopious.com/images/store_logos/original/9f84c96905ade833f48054cda524c7960dc0f424.png") no-repeat;
background-position:-500px -50px;   
}
```

and remove the img from html.
this gives the effect of zooming

Answer (score 0):

```
.box-container img {width:100%; 
height:auto;}
```

Add above code to your css. So that image will not squezeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the image element from the HTML and use `background-image` in your CSS instead.

Then you can use the `cover` argument for the `background-size`. This will take care of zooming the image to fit the box as well as keeping it proportional:

```
.boutique-grid .box-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    background-image:url(...);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

**[MODIFIED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/3m9aK/11/)**

With this approach you won't need to worry about re-calculating the sizes as the browser will do it for you.

Use the `background-position` to fine-adjust its position.

More details on background-size:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size